# Hide/show terrain programmatically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, terrain

How to hide/show terrain and other gameObjects during run-time (by C# code)?
I want to show/hide terrain and gameObjects in a fade-in/out style

Comment: To get a "fade-in/out" style you will need a shader. WIll you tell us why you want to do this, this may help giving you an appropriate answer.

Comment: What material/shader are you using? Standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Terrain script uses a built-in shader by default. This one is not accessible nor modifiable.

```
Material mat = terrain.materialTemplate;
Debug.Log(mat==null); // True
```

Assigning a custom shader is limited to the Nature shader and none offers the use of Color. It seems in general that the terrain ignores the color of a shader.

```
    Material mat = terrain.materialTemplate;
    Color c = mat.color;
    c.a = 0.5f;  
    mat.color = c;
```

This will show the modification in the shader color but no effect on the terrain itself.

As a result you would have to create your own shader, like this one http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/TerrainTransparency

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ChangeAlpha : MonoBehaviour {
public Renderer Renderer;
private Material _material;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    _material = Renderer.material;
    StartCoroutine("ChangeAlphaSlowly");
}

private IEnumerator ChangeAlphaSlowly()
{
    var increaseAmount = 0f;
    var _color = new Color(0, 0, 1, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)//ten step 
    {
        increaseAmount += 0.1f;
        _material.color = new Color(0, 0, 1, increaseAmount);          
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: even it is not wroking on plane as well

Comment: You can use canvas and canvas group's alpha property for show/hide effect on camera. If I want to show and hide my all gameobjects  on the scene with fade in/out stlye, I use this way. Sorry, I tried to help you.